# Using UIScrollView to cycle through images

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

[image: Storyboard view of controller]

I have an imageView inside of a scrollView, and I want to be able to upload up to 3 images and have the user swipe between them. I have accomplished this simply by replacing the contents of the view with the information I want, but it doesn't look or feel as good as a scroll view with pagination would.

I have all of the code to make each image appear when I want it, but my problem is with the scrollview constraints and how to add more content to a scrollview with fixed width. No matter what I do, I can't seem to extend the scroll range when I add an image to the view.

here is what I'm trying now:

```
let newImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
self.imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.imageView.frame.size.width * 3, height: self.imageView.frame.size.height)
self.imageScrollView.pagingEnabled = true

for i = 0; i < 3; ++i {
    var xOrigin:CGFloat = CGFloat(i) * self.view.frame.size.width
    newImageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.imageView.image!.size.width * i, 0, self.imageView.image!.size.width, self.imageScrollView.frame.size.height)
    newImageView.image = images[i]
    newImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    self.imageScrollView.addSubview(newImageView)
}
```

With this code I am able to add the images, but I cannot scroll to them. In my storyboard, the scrollview constraints look like this:

[image]

I'm sure some of these constraints are redundant, but I can't figure out why the content width won't extend and allow me to scroll through all of the images in the scrollview.

**EDIT**

I have made changes by using the textbook examples from @matt. I made a new view controller and put it inside a view in my other view controller (the same one as I had originally). It displays the first one no problem, but it doesn't seem to call teh UIPageViewControllerDataSource functions when I swipe left or right. I'm not sure why this is the case.

Here's what it looks like in the original view controller (UploadPhotoViewController)

```
func setUpPageViewController() {
    sharedIm.images.append(UIImage(named: "placeholder")!)
    sharedIm.images.append(UIImage(named: "TestProfile")!)
    sharedIm.images.append(UIImage(named: "button")!)
    let pvc = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
    let page:ImagePage = ImagePage()
    pvc.dataSource = self
    pvc.setViewControllers([page], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

    pvc.view.frame = self.imageContainer.bounds
    self.imageContainer.addSubview(pvc.view)
    pvc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

//this is placed at the end of the class
extension UploadPhotoViewController : UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let image = (viewController as! ImagePage).image
    let ix = find(sharedIm.images, image)! + 1
    println(ix)
    if ix >= sharedIm.images.count {
        println("no next page")
        return nil
    }
    sharedIm.currentIndex = ix
    let page = ImagePage()
    return page
}


func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let image = (viewController as! ImagePage).image
    let ix = find(sharedIm.images, image)! - 1
    println(ix)
    if ix < 0 {
        println("no previous page")
        return nil
    }
    sharedIm.currentIndex = ix
    let page = ImagePage()
    return page
}
```

And here is what is in my new view controller that is being added to a view of the other one:

```
class ImagePage: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var image : UIImage? 
var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
@IBOutlet var imageView : UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var forwardButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var backButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var closeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var pictureButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var cameraButton: UIButton!



init() {
    self.image = sharedIm.images[sharedIm.currentIndex]
    super.init(nibName: "ImagePage", bundle: nil)
}

required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.imageView.image = self.image
}
//bunch of other code for buttons and uploading pictures
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do would be a lot easier with a UIPageViewController (with a scrolling style). I would suggest that you switch to a UIPageViewController implementation instead.

The reason is that you only supply *one* "page" (in your case, an image) at a time. You can decide *in real time* whether there is another "page" in either direction, and how many "pages" you want to pretend there "really" are. The bookkeeping work happens in your model (the data behind the scenes), rather than your having to configure the entire view to handle all pages at once, as UIScrollView makes you do.

Comment: Thanks! So in my situation, would it be best to add a container (with correct dimensions) to my existing view controller, and then add the UIPageViewController to the container?

Comment: Exactly - I'm sorry that that example didn't illustrate that. Here's one that does: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch17p700PhotoKitImages/PhotoKitImages/RootViewController.swift

Comment: Sorry if this comes off as noobish, but I can't figure out why the UIPageViewControllerDataSource functions aren't being called. I updated my question with new code adapted from your examples. 

Your textbook examples are fantastic by the way! I have seen several cool examples in them that I have/will use as ideas to refactor things I've already done (since I don't know what I'm doing at all with iOS development)

Comment: Your code looks good; I'd probably have to see your project to understand the issue with the gestures. Are you sure the methods aren't even being called? That sounds like maybe the gesture isn't even being communicated to the page view controller. Do you have user interactions enabled for `self.imageContainer`?

Comment: figured it out! I was adding pvc.view to the subview of self.imageContainer, but I wasn't doing self.addChildViewController(pvc)

Comment: I apologize for failing to spot that; I did look at your code, but not carefully enough. Custom container controllers require rather a complicated dance, as I explain here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers

Answer (score 0):

When working with autolayout and uiscrollview, the trick is to know when to load your content. Since you are working in a hybrid mode (frames and autolayout) you need to make sure the constraints have had time to load and then AFTER they have loaded, you can add your subviews and adjust the constraints.  If you try to load your content on viewDidLoad, it will be too early and your constraints may not have been set yet. If you load your content on viewWillAppear, then it's too late and the constraints have already been locked in for presenting the view to the user.

So, I have found the best place to load content is on the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` At this point autolayout has applied the constraints to your scrollView and you are now safe to make changes.  Add a call here to run your code that populates the scrollView and you should be fine.  Also, you will need to set a flag to only make the call once as `viewDidLayoutSubviews` can get called several times during view creation. You should also call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` on your scrollView to make sure its constraints are updated as you add your subviews.